# If Chrome, use WebP

Tags: performance, google-chrome, optimization, opera, webp

Because currently only Chrome and Opera supports WebP, I was wondering if I could target those two particular browsers and redirect them to fetch another version of my website so I can help optimize my site downloading speed more faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Great question, just not the right forum for it (See the FAQ)

Comment: Check $_SERVER for the user agent and then redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/ has good docs on proper setup of webP.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem like this:

- Check if the client advertises "image/webp" in Accept header
- If WebP is supported, check if the local WebP file is on disk, and
  serve it
- If server is configured as proxy, append a "WebP: true" header and
  forward to backend
- Append "Vary: Accept" if a WebP asset is served

in Nginx:

```
location / {
    if ($http_accept ~* "webp") { set $webp "true"; }
    # Use $webp variable to add correct image. 
}
```

In my case, I use thumbor software to convert images.
https://github.com/globocom/thumbor

```
pip install thumbor
```

My conf:

```
upstream thumbor  {
    server 127.0.0.1:9990;
    server 127.0.0.1:9991;
    server 127.0.0.1:9992;
    server 127.0.0.1:9993;
    server 127.0.0.1:9994;
}
location / {
    if ($http_accept ~* "webp") {
        set $webp "T";
    }
    if ($uri ~* "(jpg|jpeg)$") {
         set $webp "${webp}T";
    }
    proxy_cache_key $host$request_uri$webp;

    if ($webp = "TT") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ "/unsafe/smart/filters:format(webp)/exemple.com$uri" break;
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
        add_header Content-Disposition "inline; filename=image.webp";
    }
    if ($webp != "TT") {
        proxy_pass http://exemple.com;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a while now, thumbor supports automatic webp conversion:

https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/wiki/Configuration#auto_webp

You'll still have to configure the load balancer to pass the webp accepts header, but other than that, thumbor will take care of everything for you.

Hope that helps!